# Simple example to build a Dockerfile in Azure

Tags: azure-devops

Does anyone have a working azure-pipelines.yaml file that utilizes containers only to build Dockerfiles which I have in my repo.

```
resources:
    containers:
        - container: docker-image
          image: docker:18.09.6

jobs:
    - job: Build
      container: docker-image
      steps:
          - script: |
                echo hello from Linux
                Docker --version
```

The above ends up with the error:

```
##[section]Starting: Initialize containers
##[command]/usr/bin/docker version --format '{{.Server.APIVersion}}'
'1.40'
Docker daemon API version: '1.40'
##[command]/usr/bin/docker version --format '{{.Client.APIVersion}}'
'1.40'
Docker client API version: '1.40'
##[command]/usr/bin/docker ps --all --quiet --no-trunc --filter "label=f38b39"
##[command]/usr/bin/docker network prune --force --filter "label=f38b39"
##[command]/usr/bin/docker network create --label f38b39 vsts_network_b78f6272ef304388ac849f3f37071eea
fda578a22eeb5aae1fcd41a4b816a279d20cfa552dbe3ad366fa2a009ab35313
##[command]/usr/bin/docker pull docker:18.09.6
18.09.6: Pulling from library/docker
e7c96db7181b: Already exists
5297bd381816: Pulling fs layer
3a664477889c: Pulling fs layer
a9b893dcc701: Pulling fs layer
48bf7c1cb0dd: Pulling fs layer
555b6ea27ad2: Pulling fs layer
48bf7c1cb0dd: Waiting
555b6ea27ad2: Waiting
3a664477889c: Verifying Checksum
3a664477889c: Download complete
5297bd381816: Download complete
48bf7c1cb0dd: Verifying Checksum
48bf7c1cb0dd: Download complete
5297bd381816: Pull complete
555b6ea27ad2: Verifying Checksum
555b6ea27ad2: Download complete
a9b893dcc701: Verifying Checksum
a9b893dcc701: Download complete
3a664477889c: Pull complete
a9b893dcc701: Pull complete
48bf7c1cb0dd: Pull complete
555b6ea27ad2: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:bf929409251faa1d1fcf63af68d02bb942054cfbe14e6ad9dca0dc4a01cbffad
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker:18.09.6
docker.io/library/docker:18.09.6
##[command]/usr/bin/docker inspect --format="{{index .Config.Labels \"com.azure.dev.pipelines.agent.handler.node.path\"}}" docker:18.09.6
##[command]/usr/bin/docker create --name docker-image_docker18096_794554 --label f38b39 --network vsts_network_b78f6272ef304388ac849f3f37071eea  -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/vsts/work/1":"/__w/1" -v "/home/vsts/work/_temp":"/__w/_temp" -v "/opt/hostedtoolcache":"/__t" -v "/home/vsts/work/_tasks":"/__w/_tasks" -v "/home/vsts/agents/2.150.3/externals":"/__a/externals":ro -v "/home/vsts/work/.taskkey":"/__w/.taskkey" docker:18.09.6 "/__a/externals/node/bin/node" -e "setInterval(function(){}, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);"
b8856a42131206302453903ae8fbc85957368b2e377ee5a9d1b44627130006b0
##[command]/usr/bin/docker start b8856a42131206302453903ae8fbc85957368b2e377ee5a9d1b44627130006b0
b8856a42131206302453903ae8fbc85957368b2e377ee5a9d1b44627130006b0
##[command]/usr/bin/docker ps --all --filter id=b8856a42131206302453903ae8fbc85957368b2e377ee5a9d1b44627130006b0 --filter status=running --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}} {{.Status}}"
b8856a42131206302453903ae8fbc85957368b2e377ee5a9d1b44627130006b0 Up Less than a second
##[command]/usr/bin/docker exec  b8856a42131206302453903ae8fbc85957368b2e377ee5a9d1b44627130006b0 sh -c "command -v bash"
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: cannot exec a container that has stopped: unknown
##[error]Docker exec fail with exit code 126
##[section]Finishing: Initialize containers
```

Answer (score -1):

that's because that container doesnt run endlessly if you just start it, it exits, change `docker:18.09.6` to `ubuntu` or something that doesnt exit immediately and it will work.